# How get information from tag use node.js and library puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, scrape, puppeteer

Page source is different from page in browser. Therefore I need use puppeteer library or jsdom library.

The page have tag "div" and many classes "bma-fly flying flying-won-team2 flying-past":

How get information from this tag???

I use code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var fs = require('fs');

var link = "www. la la la . com";

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(link);
  const text2 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.bma-fly.flying.flying-won-team2.flying-past').innerHTML);
  console.log(text2);
  fs.writeFileSync("a08.txt" , text2);
  browser.close();
})();
```

If I use:

```
const text1 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("div.bma-fly.flying.flying-won-team2.flying-past").innerHTML);
```

I get information only from first time this element is found. 
**How get other information where this tag and this class?**

If not use innerHTML , I get: `{}` in console. (I use Linux).

If I save use `fs.writeFileSync("a07.txt" , text1);` , I get `[object Object]`.

If I use `.childNodes` I get

`{ '0': {}, '1': {}, '2': {}, '3': {}, '4': {}, '5': {}, '6': {} }`

in console. 
If I save this, I get: `[object Object]`.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

To select all of the nodes using that selector, you need `document.querySelectorAll()`.

```
// get html element refs to 
var els = document.querySelectorAll('div.bma-fly.flying.flying-won-team2.flying-past')

// convert nodelist to array, then map the innerHTML property
var htmls = Array.prototype.slice.apply(els).map(el => el.innerHTML)
```

This will give you an array of all values for your selector.

`["asdf", "asdfdsf", ...]`

If you are writing a json object to a text file, you need to convert it into a string. This can be done with `JSON.stringify()`.

In your case, it would look like this:

`fs.writeFileSync("a07.txt" , JSON.stringify(text1))`